# What's the handle for media.js?

Tags: javascript

I want to use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load [`media.js`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-admin/js/media.dev.js) from frond end. I use Win Grep searching through the whole WP dir, couldn't find which handle this `media.js` was registered.
in this `media.js` , there's a function `findpost.open` , that's what I need.
Could anybody tell the handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle is `media`. [View in source, line 403](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L403).

Comment: I believe for most of the javascript files, the filename is the same as the handle.

Comment: Got it, thanks! However, it can't be loaded, firebug says forbidden. so, I have to copy it into my plugin dir to load it.